# Trouble adding background image to div in Django site

Tags: css, django

I want to add a background image to a div that is a row in Bootstrap in Django site. My CSS says:

```
.bimage {

  background-image: url("{% static 'home/images/background.jpg' %}");

}
```

I confirmed that the jpg is in the right folder. Could something else be wrong?

Comment: Try getting rid of the curly braces, %, and static

Comment: is this in a css file or inside the template header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in a css file, then use `../../` to go up the directory, and then to `home->images` directory. You can't use django template tags in a css file.

**For example** if your css file is in `static/css/style.css` and your image is in `static/home/images/background.jpg`, then you would:

```
background-image: url("../home/images/background.jpg");
```

If your css is not in a css file, rather in the header of your template, then make sure you've setup `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` properly in your `settings.py` file.

If that's not the issue, then make sure you've loaded statics `{% load static %}` in your template.

If that's not the issue, then try `python manage.py collectstatic`.

Last but not least, make sure you're pointing to the right directory.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the these tips!

Answer (score 0):

Does your div have a **width** and a **height**? Then ensure that your background image is not too big. If it is, only a part of it will be displayed.

```
.bimage {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("{% static 'home/images/background.jpg' %}") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

You may need to adjust these values to fit to your design. Make also sure that your iamge is being loaded. Do you have any 404 errors displayed in your **browser console**?

Comment: I don't get a 404 error - unless I remove the curley brackets, %s and static. The div does not have a width or height. I also tried background and background-image and neither worked

Comment: Inspect the code with your browser. A div typically has no height and width if no content is being added. To make the background image visible, set a width and a height. Also, check if the outputted link in your CSS leads to the desired image.